# Auto trigger gitlab cicd when code changes in github repo

Tags: github, gitlab-ci, webhooks, github-actions, gitlab-ci-runner

I am using Github for code and using GitLab CiCd for pipeline, Manual trigger is working fine but I am trying to auto trigger the pipeline when the new Changes is pushes to the code. Please suggest ideas.

Comment: If you don't mind an extra tool we support this via Reliza Hub - http://docs.relizahub.com/integrations/#ci-integrations . Essentially, you need to leverage GitHub Actions to send some metadata and then Reliza Hub would trigger the build on GitLab. If you want to try this route - reach out to me on our Discord, will help with set up - https://discord.gg/UTxjBf9juQ

Answer (score 0):

You could use a **Gitlab CI action** from a Github repository workflow with Github Actions.

**Action example:** [Trigger Gitlab CI Job](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/trigger-gitlab-ci-job)

*Note: [Others Github Actions interacting with Gitlab can be found on the marketplace](https://github.com/marketplace?type=actions&query=gitlab%20)*

**Github Action workflow example:**

```
name: trigger gitlab job
on: [push]
jobs:

  build:
    name: Build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: trigger Job
      uses: appleboy/gitlab-ci-action@master
      with:
        url: "http://example.com"
        token: ${{ secrets.TOKEN }}
        project_id: 100
```

**Where the input variables are:**

***token** - Required. A unique trigger token can be obtained when adding a new trigger.*

***project_id** - Required. project id.*

***ref** - Optional. Triggers can be used to force a pipeline rerun of a specific ref (branch or tag) with an API call. Default as master.*